# Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Tags: android

whet i am starting new Activity using this way below

```
Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), WebViewLink.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
edit.putExtra(POSITION, FAQ);
parentActivity.startChildActivity("WebViewLink", edit);
```

I am getting error like this

```
08-19 13:44:49.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44dabdc8 is not valid; is your activity running?
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:468)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at com.stress.WebViewLink$2.onLoadResource(WebViewLink.java:73)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:355)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but when I am using this way for call new Activity There is no problem

```
Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), WebViewLink.class);
edit.putExtra(POSITION, FAQ);
More.this.startActivity(edit);
```

you can see My WebViewLink.java class here

```
public class WebViewLink extends Activity {
public static String POSITION = "position";
int position = 0;
private Button back;
private TextView ttl;
ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;
private WebView webView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backtomore);
    ttl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_title);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(POSITION)) {
            position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(POSITION);
        }
    }
    switch (position) {
    case More.FAQ:
        ttl.setText("FAQ");
        setWebLink();
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/faq4.htm");
        break;
    case More.ABOUT_US:
        ttl.setText("About Us");
        setWebLink();
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Advice/About Us.html");
        break;
    case More.DISCLAIMMER:
        ttl.setText("Disclaimer");
        setWebLink();
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Advice/Disclaimer.html");
        break;
    }
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void setWebLink() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            if (myProgressDialog == null) {
                myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewLink.this);
                myProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading.... Please Wait");
                myProgressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (myProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewLink.this);
```

when you are you `TabGroupActivity` then child `Activity`(ies) need parents' `Context` to add new Windows, Dialogs. Try this way:

```
myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewLink.this.getParent());
```

and do the same for all `Dialog`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
08-19 13:44:49.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44dabdc8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

above error says your activity is not running.So,when you call this activity using following instruction then program crash.because it cant get any activity.

```
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
```